# C# Generics - a generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, higher-kinded-types

I have the following generic type hierarchy:

```
interface IGenericInterface<TId, TValue>
{…}

class A : IGenericInterface<long, string>
```

I want to design a generic type that takes IGenericInterface as type.
The solution allowed by the compiler is:

```
class SomeType<TType, TId, TValue> where TType : IGenericInterface<TId, TValue>
```

When I need to inherit such a type, I need to specify:

```
class Derived : SomeType<A, long, string>
```

This looks like a redundancy to specify 2nd and 3rd type arguments, because class A is already of `IGenericInterface<long, string>`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want - Derived class in a more elegant fashion?

Comment: So essentially you want `TType` to be any `IGenericInterface`? I don't think this is possible...

Comment: Right, any IGenericInterface

Comment: @Sweeper I think the question is "How do I avoid typing `long, string` in `class Derived : SomeType<A, long, string>`, because `long, string` should be _inferred_ from the `A` type I'm using?"

Comment: And I don't think that sort of inference is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an intermediate interface and have `SomeType` constrain against that instead. Something like:

```
interface IA : IGenericInterface<long,string> { }

class A : IA {}

class SomeType<TType> where TType : IA { }

class Derived : SomeType<A> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right your point is sensible, unfortunately it is *not yet* supported. What you are after is called *higher kinded parametric polymorphism*, a feature dearly wanted by functional programming enthusiasts.

[Roslyn feature](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/339)

Comment: [This is the modern migration of the feature request linked.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/339)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help? (I think `IEnumerable` does something similar)

```
internal interface IGenericInterface
interface IGenericInterface <TId, TValue> : IGenericInterface
class SomeType<TType> where TType : IGenericInterface
```